# MVC 5 / Bootstrap Rendering Inconsistency

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my Bootstrap MVC 5 app, I have a page where there is a table div on the left and a Google Maps div on the right. The HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-5">
        <table id="listingTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover table-condensed sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody class="searchable">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-6">
        <div id="googleMap" style="height:350px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initially this displays exactly as it should. For XS, S and MD displays, I get the Google maps div underneath the table div. For large, I get them side by side. However, if I slowly shrink the width of the browser, while in LG size, the Google div will start to overwrite the right hand side of table until I reach the MD size and then it moves underneath the table, as it should. My question is this. Why is the Google Maps div overwriting the right hand portion of the table while in LG display, and can this be 'fixed'?

Comment: I have encountered similar situation, but I took it as "that is how it's supposed to be". Now that you mentioned this, I m curious what is the root cause the what is the solution!